# Angular 4, insert multiple components

Tags: angular

Im making an application in angular 4 where the users can choose which graphs that should show in thier view. They should be able to pick X nr graph and they should be able to show same graph twice if they choose to.

So I was thinking to build a string of my components:

```
this.test = '<app-overview [price]=this.price [selectedSymbol]=this.selectedSymbol></app-overview>'
```

and then render in in the html. Since its possible to choose multiple graphs I want to loop over them with an ng-for. What is the best practice for this in angular 4?

Comment: What is angular 4? Do you mean angular 2?

Comment: version angular 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert component dynamically(https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and you can pass input to them dynamically too.